# Cannot convert UInt64 to AggregateFunction(avg, UInt64)

Tags: clickhouse

I'm a beginner at ClickHouse DB. I create an aggregation table by the following:

```
create table tb_test (
`id` String,
`uid` String,
`x` SimpleAggregateFunction(sum, UInt64),
`y` SimpleAggregateFunction(sum, UInt64),
`z` AggregateFunction(avg, UInt64)
)  ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree()
ORDER BY (id,uid)
```

But when I try to insert into it by `insert into tb_test values ('a','b',1,1,1)` it gives me an error:

> Code: 53. DB::Exception: Cannot convert UInt64 to AggregateFunction(avg, UInt64): While executing ValuesBlockInputFormat. (TYPE_MISMATCH) (version 22.2.2.1)

What's the right way to insert into this table?

Answer (score 1):

It needs to use [*INSERT SELECT*](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/aggregatingmergetree#select-and-insert) query:

```sql
INSERT INTO tb_test SELECT
    'a',
    'b',
    1,
    1,
    avgState(toUInt64(1))
```

Comment: It yields `NaN` in column `z`!!

Answer (score 1):

input function https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/table-functions/input/

```sql
INSERT INTO tb_test 
SELECT id,uid,sum(x), sum(y), avgState(z) 
FROM input('id String, uid String, x UInt64, y UInt64, z UInt64') 
group by id, uid 
format Values ('a','b',1,1,1);

select id, uid, x, y, finalizeAggregation(z) z from tb_test;
┌─id─┬─uid─┬─x─┬─y─┬─z─┐
│ a  │ b   │ 1 │ 1 │ 1 │
└────┴─────┴───┴───┴───┘
```

engine Null https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/special/null

```sql
create table N (id String, uid String, x UInt64, y UInt64, z UInt64) 
Engine Null;

create materialized view mvN to tb_test as
SELECT id,uid,sum(x) x, sum(y) y, avgState(z) z
from N
group by id, uid;

insert into N values ('a','b',1,1,1);

select id, uid, x, y, finalizeAggregation(z) z from tb_test;
┌─id─┬─uid─┬─x─┬─y─┬─z─┐
│ a  │ b   │ 1 │ 1 │ 1 │
└────┴─────┴───┴───┴───┘
┌─id─┬─uid─┬─x─┬─y─┬─z─┐
│ a  │ b   │ 1 │ 1 │ 1 │
└────┴─────┴───┴───┴───┘

optimize table tb_test final;

select id, uid, x, y, finalizeAggregation(z) z from tb_test;
┌─id─┬─uid─┬─x─┬─y─┬─z─┐
│ a  │ b   │ 2 │ 2 │ 1 │
└────┴─────┴───┴───┴───┘
```

Comment: Thanks denny! I insert more than 100 rec every second and retrieve it continuously. So I think these methods is not efficient. I'd like something like `SummingMergeTree` but calculating average also.

Comment: hahaha, just try them. There is no impact on performance.

Comment: You can use SummingMergeTree and store two columns sum/count

Comment: also probably I can remove group by using initializeAggregation, but it's premature optimization at this point.